# How to retain the resizing with Bootstrap 4 as the screen gets smaller with an image that is a link?

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-4

I need to get the images in the second container on the right to switch from vertical on the right to horizontal under the first container, and get smaller, as the screen gets smaller. It worked before I added the "< a href..." The link works. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried a few different solutions, including moving `col-md-10 col-sm-3` from inside the "< img class="..."" to the "< a href" section and changing `img-responsive` to `img-fluid`, but can't seem to get it to resize.

```
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="container col-lg-7">
            <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">

                <h1>Summary: Lorem Ipsum<hr/></h1>
                <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-responsive shadow float-left col-md-4" alt="200x200" src="Lorem Ipsum.png" data-holder-rendered="true">

                <p class="text-left lead">Lorem Ipsum<br><br>

                Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container col-lg-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum<hr/></h1>
                <a class= "col-md-10 col-sm-3" href="Lorem Ipsum.html">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="Lorem Ipsum.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
                </a>
                <a class= "col-md-10 col-sm-3" href="Lorem Ipsum.html">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="Lorem Ipsum.png"data-holder-rendered="true">
                </a>
                <a class= "col-md-10 col-sm-3" href="Lorem Ipsum.html">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="Lorem Ipsum.png"data-holder-rendered="true">
                </a>
                <a class= "col-md-10 col-sm-3" href="Lorem Ipsum.html">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="Lorem Ipsum.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this before the body section `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The answer was to put each image and link into a separate container and add `col-3` for the extra small page size.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container col-md-10 col-sm-3 col-3">
        <a href="Lorem.html">
        <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="Lorems.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="container col-md-10 col-sm-3 col-3">
        <a href="Lorem.html">
        <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="Lorems.png"data-holder-rendered="true">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="container col-md-10 col-sm-3 col-3">
        <a href="Lorem.html">
        <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="Lorems.png"data-holder-rendered="true">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="container col-md-10 col-sm-3 col-3">
        <a  href="Lorem.html">
        <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="Lorems.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, you should definitely use `img-fluid` to get the images to resize, [see the bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#images)

In order to make your images align horizontally when using an sm-screen, you should put them in an element with `display: flex`. Just using the `d-flex` class causes problems with wrapping on larger screens, so `row` seems to be your best option:

```
<div class="container col-lg-3">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">Lorem Ipsum<hr/></h1>
      <div class="row">
           <a class= "col-md-10 col-sm-3" href="Lorem Ipsum.html">
            <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
           </a>
           <a class= "col-md-10 col-sm-3" href="Lorem Ipsum.html">
            <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png"data-holder-rendered="true">
           </a>
           <a class= "col-md-10 col-sm-3" href="Lorem Ipsum.html">
             <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png"data-holder-rendered="true">
           </a>
           <a class= "col-md-10 col-sm-3" href="Lorem Ipsum.html">
                <img data-src="holder.js/200x200" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block shadow" alt="200x200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3m548L9h/) to show this working.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work for me. I did however find the answer and have posted it above. I don't know why your answer didn't work though.